# Select parent rows and include cost of children

Tags: oracle, group-by, sum, oracle-18c

I have a WORKORDER table that has parent and child WOs in it:

```
with workorder as (
select 'WO37342' as wonum,      null as parent, 297.36 as actlabcost, 200 as actmatcost, 0 as actservcost, 0 as acttoolcost from dual
union all
select 'WO37427' as wonum, 'WO37342' as parent,  99.12 as actlabcost,   0 as actmatcost, 0 as actservcost, 0 as acttoolcost from dual
union all
select 'WO37429' as wonum, 'WO37342' as parent,  99.12 as actlabcost, 100 as actmatcost, 0 as actservcost, 0 as acttoolcost from dual
)
select
    * 
from
    workorder

 WONUM   PARENT  ACTLABCOST ACTMATCOST ACTSERVCOST ACTTOOLCOST
 ------- ------- ---------- ---------- ----------- -----------
 WO37342             297.36        200           0           0
 WO37427 WO37342      99.12          0           0           0
 WO37429 WO37342      99.12        100           0           0
```

---

I want to select the parent rows and include the cost of the children in the parents:

```
 WONUM    ACTLABCOST ACTMATCOST ACTSERVCOST ACTTOOLCOST
 ------- ----------- ---------- ----------- -----------
 WO37342       495.6        300           0           0
```

---

Is there a concise way of doing this with Oracle 18c SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ability was available in Oracle 7; maybe earlier. ( [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SQL73/ch4a.htm#toc171) )

1. Use a hierarchical query (in a CTE/sub-query) to find the children and grandchildren.
2. `SUM()` the values when you `GROUP BY` the parent `wonum`.

```sql
with workorder as (
    select 'WO37342' as wonum,      null as parent, 297.36 as actlabcost, 200 as actmatcost, 0 as actservcost, 0 as acttoolcost from dual
    union all
    select 'WO37427' as wonum, 'WO37342' as parent,  99.12 as actlabcost,   0 as actmatcost, 0 as actservcost, 0 as acttoolcost from dual
    union all
    select 'WO37429' as wonum, 'WO37342' as parent,  99.12 as actlabcost, 100 as actmatcost, 0 as actservcost, 0 as acttoolcost from dual
), hier as (
    select connect_by_root( wonum ) parent_wonum
        ,level lv
        ,a.*
    from workorder a
    start with a.parent is null
    connect by a.parent = prior(a.wonum)
)
select parent_wonum
    ,listagg(wonum,',') within group (order by lv, wonum) list_wo
    ,sum( actlabcost ) actlabcost
    ,sum( actmatcost ) actmatcost
    ,sum( actservcost ) actservcost
    ,sum( acttoolcost ) acttoolcost
from hier
group by parent_wonum
```